# How to draw paths of decreasing width in android canvas?

Tags: android, path, effects

[image]I wanted to draw path effect in android canvas like, the path should give the actual feel like a brush. The path should not start or end with linear width. While starting, width should be increasing linearly up to given width and while ending the reverse, width should be decreasing. It would be helpful if we can do the same for the opacity of the line. The path effect should be as following.

Is there any direct way to do it in android? Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way to go about accomplishing this would be to render a (filled) polygon instead? Create a new path using `moveTo` `lineTo` `lineTo`, etc to define your brush stroke. Once completed and closed, fill the triangle with the appropriate command. Android also supports passing your vertices and colors in an array using the `drawVertices` method. Good luck~!

Comment: what if the path ends have the sharp curves? I can't draw a triangle directly there, right?

Comment: You'll be surprised what can be made out of triangles =]

Comment: Let's put it this way -- if they can create photo-realistic video games using triangles and polygons, then for sure you can create a realistic brush stroke. Why don't you post a picture of the effect you are looking for so people can further advise?

Comment: I have added a snap of the path effect.